# How to list users by role on page?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I have many user roles on my site.

All users have profile information(custom fileds added).

In a page I want to show 3 type of roles users  like like

```
Role1 :

picture |  name | email | phone no

.....
.....

Role2 :

picture |  name | email | phone no

.....
.....


Role3 :

picture |  name | email | phone no

.....
.....
```

Using view(Filter) to we can list users by role or anything else but i want to show 3 roles based users with above custom format.

Do we have option like this view?
or Can i create 3 views for each role and finally merge it? or Do i want to write custom code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Advanced section` of the view, click to add new `Contextual filters` then choose `User: Roles`

Now you can list the users filtered by the `Role ID`.

like: `users-page/2` will list users who have authenticated user role, `users-page/3` will list users who have administrator role, and so on.

**Update 1**:

In the section `Configure contextual filter: User: Roles`, open `More` fieldset in the bottom.

Then access the page like `users-page/3+4` will list users who have administrator role and the role id 4.

**Update 2**:

Add the `roles` to the fields and check `Exclude form display`. Then under `Format` -> `Settings` select `Grouping field` to `Roles`.

Comment: Updated the answer, kindly recheck.

Comment: no. I want role1 label and its users list then role2 lable and its users list then role3... It all things i want in one page.

Comment: Updated the answer, kindly recheck.